# Accessing Static Fields From FreeMarker Template (Spring)

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker, templating

I want to access static properties from FreeMarker Template

I have a class say Global which contains Static Final Fields and this class is not part of 
the FreeMarker model. I want to know if there is a way to add this class to FreeMarker model
at startup of my app and access from Freemarker template like this:

```
${statics["com.ums.common.Global"].Change}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dataModel.put("statics", ((BeansWrapper) cfg.getObjectWrapper()).getStaticModels());
```

where `cfg` is the FreeMarker `Configuration` object. Then you can use `statics['com.example.ClassName'].FIELD_NAME` to access the static fields or methods. You can also use something like

```
dataModel.put("globals", ((BeansWrapper) cfg.getObjectWrapper()).getStaticModels().get("com.ums.common.Global"));
```

if you only want to expose the constants of that class.

Comment: great! but i want to do this at application startup so that it is available immediately what is better?
A Filter where i do 
request.setAttribute("globals", ((BeansWrapper) cfg.getObjectWrapper()).getStaticModels().get("com.ums.common.Global"));
or there is some good approach definitely there will be

Comment: You could use `cfg.setSharedVariable("globals", ((BeansWrapper) cfg.getObjectWrapper()).getStaticModels().get("com.ums.common.Global"))` where you configure FreeMarker at application startup. Only be careful to do it after the `objectWrapper` property of the `Configuration` object has its final value, or else your app will use two wrappers at once for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Spring configuration class to configure Freemarker and use the Freemarker `configuration.setSharedVariables()` method to enable access to static methods from any template.  The shared variables is also very useful for putting global properties (e.g. from your `application.yaml` file) so they are globally available from any template.

```java
@Configuration
public class FreemarkerConfig implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Value("${email.from-address}")         // e.g. from `application.yaml`
    private String emailFromAddress;

    @SneakyThrows         // or use try / catch (if not using lombok)
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof FreeMarkerConfigurer) {
            FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = (FreeMarkerConfigurer) bean;
            freemarker.template.Configuration configuration = configurer.getConfiguration();
            BeansWrapper objectWrapper = (BeansWrapper) configuration.getObjectWrapper();
            configuration.setSharedVariables(getSharedVariables(objectWrapper));
        }
        return bean;
    }

    private Map<String, ?> getSharedVariables(BeansWrapper config) {
        Map<String, Object> sharedVariables = new HashMap<>();

        // Add global variables
        sharedVariables.put("emailFromAddress", emailFromAddress);

        // Add static support
        TemplateModel statics = config.getStaticModels();
        sharedVariables.put("statics", statics);
        return sharedVariables;
    }

}
```

Once the configuration is set up, you can add access your shared variables in any template (e.g. `${emailFromAddress}`).

To access static methods you first of all need to link the class containing the static method.  For example, if you wanted to do a more bespoke comparison of 2 objects you might have: -

```java
public class FreemarkerUtils {

    /**
     * Compare 2 objects.  Both objects are converted to Strings first of all (empty String if null) and compared.
     */
    public static boolean isEqualTo(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        String str1 = obj1 != null ? String.valueOf(obj1) : "";
        String str2 = obj2 != null ? String.valueOf(obj2) : "";

        return str1.equals(str2);
    }

}
```

This static method must be assigned as follows in a freemarker template ...

```
<#assign Util=statics['com.my.package.FreemarkerUtils']>
```

... and used as follows ...

```
<#if Util.isEqualTo (obj1, obj2)> objects are equal! </#if>
```

Using Java static methods like this from your templates can be useful when Freemarker isn't powerful enough for your particular use-case.